# DB2 case statement for updating a table but multiple columns

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, case

I am trying to merge 4 separate update statements into one single update statement.
I have no experience with case statements or if what I'm attempting to do would even work.

Any input on how to structure this?
This is my attempt, but it's not working.

```
  UPDATE URL
  SET CONTENT_TITLE =
  CASE
     WHEN ID = ? AND SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 OR ID = ? AND SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE != '' AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
     WHEN ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NULL AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 OR ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE = '' AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
     WHEN ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
     WHEN ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NULL AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599 OR ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE = '' AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
  SET CONTENT_DSCR =
  CASE
     WHEN ID = ? AND CONTENT_DSCR IS NULL AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 OR ID = ? AND CONTENT_DSCR = '' AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
     WHEN ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
  SET SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = 'title and dscr update'
  SET UPDATED_ON = SYSDATE
  END
```

Here are the placeholders (?) I'm using:

```
u.urlId, 'title and dscr update', u.statusCode, u.urlId, 'title and dscr update', 
u.statusCode, u.contentTitle, u.urlId, u.statusCode, u.urlId, u.statusCode, 
u.contentTitle, u.urlId, u.statusCode, null, null, u.urlId, u.statusCode, u.urlId, 
u.statusCode, u.contentDescription, u.urlId, u.statusCode, 'title and dscr update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it won't help at all, but - let me try (as there's no reply for *hours*):

I don't know DB2; if its SQL is anything similar to Oracle's then

- `CASE` should have its `END`
- there's only one `SET` keyword in the whole `UPDATE` statement
- logically, when there's `OR`, you should use parentheses (otherwise you'll get *unexpected* result)

Something like this:

```
UPDATE URL
  SET CONTENT_TITLE =
        CASE
           WHEN     (ID = ? AND SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ?  AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599) 
                 OR (ID = ? AND SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = ?  AND CONTENT_TITLE != ''       AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599) THEN ?
           WHEN     (ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NULL     AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599) 
                 OR (ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE = ''        AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599) THEN ?
           WHEN      ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
           WHEN     (ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NULL AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599) 
                 OR (ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE = ''    AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599) THEN ?
        END,           
  CONTENT_DSCR =
        CASE
           WHEN    (ID = ? AND CONTENT_DSCR IS NULL AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599) 
                OR (ID = ? AND CONTENT_DSCR = ''    AND ? NOT BETWEEN 400 AND 599) THEN ?
           WHEN ID = ? AND CONTENT_TITLE IS NOT NULL AND ? BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN ?
        END,     
  SYSTEM_UPDATE_REASON = 'title and dscr update',
  UPDATED_ON = SYSDATE
```

Comment: I am getting this error:

The statement was not processed because the statement contains an invalid use of one of the following: an untyped parameter marker, the DEFAULT keyword, or a null value.